# SQL: Need to get a count of records

Tags: asp.net, sql

This should be simple Im just not getting the desired result, i've tries this a couple of ways and still not getting anywhere I need to get the total cound of records of the subquery I know this is totally wrong but when but when I put the count on the subquery it still gives me 1 here's my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [COUNT] 
    (
        SELECT WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
        FROM WP_BlogEntries INNER JOIN sys_Objects_Tags ON
        WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID = sys_Objects_Tags.SystemObjectRecordID
        WHERE WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate < GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate > GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Approved = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Listed = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.BlogID = @BlogID
        AND TagID = @TagID
        GROUP BY WP_BlogEntries.BlogID, BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As [COUNT] 
From (
    SELECT WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
    FROM WP_BlogEntries 
        INNER JOIN sys_Objects_Tags 
            ON WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID = sys_Objects_Tags.SystemObjectRecordID
    WHERE WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate < GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate > GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Approved = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Listed = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.BlogID = @BlogID
        AND TagID = @TagID
    GROUP BY WP_BlogEntries.BlogID, BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
    ) As Z
```

You simply need to alias the subquery and put it into the FROM clause making it into a derived table. Although, if all you want is the count, you don't need anything in the Select clause (i.e., you could use `Select 1` in the subquery's Select clause and it'd still work.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does this return with your normal parameters in @BlogID, @TagID?:

```
SELECT WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
        FROM WP_BlogEntries INNER JOIN sys_Objects_Tags ON
        WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID = sys_Objects_Tags.SystemObjectRecordID
        WHERE WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate < GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate > GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Approved = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Listed = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.BlogID = @BlogID
        AND TagID = @TagID
        GROUP BY WP_BlogEntries.BlogID, BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
```

And, as others have pointed out, your inner query needs a name:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
        FROM WP_BlogEntries INNER JOIN sys_Objects_Tags ON
        WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID = sys_Objects_Tags.SystemObjectRecordID
        WHERE WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate < GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate > GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Approved = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.Listed = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.BlogID = @BlogID
        AND TagID = @TagID
        GROUP BY WP_BlogEntries.BlogID, BlogEntryID, sys_Objects_Tags.TagID
) PLEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)as COUNT from (select * from tableName where condition='this' group by ID)as s
```